# NameError: name 'json_normalize' is not defined

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am running in python 3x with Jupyter and it is running fine and then one minute i faced the above error:
i tried to used my previous backup and faces the same error...

I encounter this problem while trying to make my code run in python rather then in jupter. and i believe it could be due to me running pip install pandas etc in the command line?
apart from that i am not sure what else i did that case the change:

```
import requests
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
....
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
data=response.json()

print(data)
df=json_normalize(data['indicator'] ,'values')
df = df.drop(df.columns[[1, 2, 3,4]], axis=1)
print(df)
```

I tried adding a import pandas but it also doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize`

Comment: from your code snippet, it seems like json_normalize is nowhere imported

Comment: Thanks lots , i know its noob.  but why does it works in Jupter in the same code before this ?

Answer (score 5):

`json_normalize` is provided by `pandas.io.json`. You need to import it:

```py
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

In the following link you can find examples about how to use it: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

If you have similar problems in the future, check your imports.

Comment: Thanks alot , but if i had import pandas , doesnt it automatically imports all the pandas.io xxx etc?

Comment: Yes, but in this case you have to use `df=pandas.io.json.json_normalize...` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

> Adding this on top of saulotoledo answer

```
FutureWarning: pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated, use pandas.json_normalize instead
```

`json_normalize` is now provided by `pandas.json_normalize` You need to import it:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

Answer (score 2):

use - pandas.json_normalize or just pd.json_normalize

```
  from pandas.io.json import json_normalize has been deprecated
```